# Group data by date from two SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following tables:

```
tbl1
------------

id   name   creationdate

0    AA     2015.05.11
1    BB     2015.04.27
2    cC     2015.04.18


tbl2
------------

id   name   creationdate

0    DD     2015.04.17
1    FF     2015.04.27
2    NN     2015.05.01
3    BV     2015.05.01
```

What would be the correct syntax for a query to group the count of rows from both table by dates? So that the result is:

```
DATE         TBL1_COUNT   TBL2_COUNT

2015.04.17            0            1
2015.04.18            1            0
2015.04.27            1            1
2015.05.01            0            2
2015.05.11            1            0
```

So far I have managed to get the dates from both tables using:

```
select  DISTINCT date(creationdate) from tbl1
union
select  DISTINCT date(creationdate) from tbl2
```

The next part would be getting count(*) from both tables and grouping them by the above query's result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient way is to have two queries: one that counts all grouped dates from table1 and set the count of table2 to 0, one other that counts all grouped dates from table2 and sets the count of table1 to 0, and then combine them using a UNION ALL query, group again and sum the resulting counts:

```
SELECT creationDate, sum(count_t1), sum(count_t2)
FROM (
  SELECT creationDate, COUNT(*) AS count_t1, 0 AS count_t2
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY creationDate

  UNION ALL

  SELECT creationDate, 0 AS count_t1, COUNT(*) AS count_t2
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY creationDate
) s
GROUP BY creationDate
```

Comment: there is an extra group by clause , you can get rid of it modifying logic.

Comment: @A.B which group by would you remove? of course it's possible, but this query is often more efficient

Comment: this will still work, i think ?  "SELECT creationDate, sum(count_t1), sum(count_t2)
FROM (
  SELECT creationDate, 1 AS count_t1, 0 AS count_t2
  FROM t1
 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT creationDate, 0 AS count_t1, 1 AS count_t2
  FROM t2
  
) s
GROUP BY creationDate" @fthiella

Comment: @A.B yes, your query is correct, but i think it will be (often, not always) slower, because mysql would probably create a temporary table with all rows from table1 and table2 before doing the group by. My query will still create a temporary table before the outer group by but with fewer rows, so it should be more efficient. Of course, better to have creationDate columns indexed.

Comment: All of the answers are educative and correct, but this seems to be the most efficent. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @fthiella sorry for my lack of knowledge, but grouping wont be an extra operation? will it first get all rows and group them? i dont know much about it

Comment: @astralmaster without indexes, xQberts answer should outperform this one because it only groups once, and hence less filesorting going on.  compare here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7ea2/2

Comment: @A.B yes the cost of three group by is higher than the cost of a single group by, but the cost of filling a temporary table with all rows is much higher than the advantage of the single group by. This of course is not always guaranteed, if you have a lot of rows with a lot of different dates both queries will create a lot of temporary rows, but I think it's a very specific case, other than that this should often perform better.

Comment: @fthiella okay thanks for sharing this info, i wasnt aware of this effeciency of temp table filling case, it seems to make sense. will try it and will compare benchmarks

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to use `UNION ALL` or the distinct aspect of union will
   eliminate the duplicates and negatively impact your counts.
2. You need a way to denote which value is from what table so we add a column to distinguish, so I added 1 for tbl1 and 2 for tbl2 and called the column src.
3. We then add a case statement in the outer select and a sum to get the desired counts and a group by to aggregate the dates..
4. Polish it off with an order by and you get what you're after.

.

```
SELECT creationDate as Date, 
  sum(case when src=1 then 1 else 0 end) as tbl1_count, 
  sum(case when src=2 then 1 else 0 end) as tbl2_count
FROM (
  SELECT creationdate, 1 as src
  FROM tbl1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT creationdate, 2 as src
  FROM tbl2) Sub
GROUP BY CreationDate
ORDER BY CreationDate
```

Comment: yeah needed to use sum not count.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good start. If I were approaching this, I would start by getting a date and count from each table, like this:

```
SELECT creationDate, COUNT(*) AS numRows
FROM t1
GROUP BY creationDate;
```

Then, you can do a FULL OUTER join to get all pairings. MySQL doesn't have full join built in, but you can emulate it using a union of a right join and a left join, try this:

```
SELECT t1.creationDate, t1.numRows AS t1Rows, COALESCE(t2.numRows, 0) AS t2Rows
FROM(
  SELECT creationDate, COUNT(*) AS numRows
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY creationDate) t1
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT creationDate, COUNT(*) AS numRows
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY creationDate) t2 ON t1.creationDate = t2.creationDate
UNION
SELECT t2.creationDate, COALESCE(t1.numRows, 0) AS t1Rows, t2.numRows AS t2Rows
FROM(
  SELECT creationDate, COUNT(*) AS numRows
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY creationDate) t1
RIGHT JOIN(
  SELECT creationDate, COUNT(*) AS numRows
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY creationDate) t2 ON t1.creationDate = t2.creationDate;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6f45/4) example.

Answer (score 1):

You can simluate a full outer join, basically. `union distinct` is fine, and actually desired, we just have to make sure we include sufficient columns to allow the distinct selection to be accurate to our needs.

```
select d3, count(d1), count(d2)
from (
select t1.id id1, t2.id id2, t1.date as d1, t2.date as d2, coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) d3
  from tbl1 t1
    left join tbl2 t2
      on t1.date = t2.date
union 
select t1.id id1, t2.id id2, t1.date as d1, t2.date as d2, coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) d3
  from tbl1 t1
    right join tbl2 t2
      on t1.date = t2.date
) q
group by d3;
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaa3b/21

Comment: ... and the 4am brain makes this way overcomplicated. leaving it here anyway because it works

Comment: Shoot, it's 4 AM for you and it's still half the size of mine. I gave the rookie simple answer.